# How to sum value of a field of all entries in a View?

Tags: 7, views

### I have a view that displays nodes. These nodes have a field and I need to sum all values of this field for all entries the view is "displaying"(not only the currently visible entries/current page but all entries that match the current Views filter).

So all I want is to add this information into the Views template file. So I have the view object available. I was trying to get rid of the pager so I could get all results but without any success. I was able to re-run the query and everything I needed beside excluding the pager. Any idea how to do this? I tried to unset the pager, change it to another module('none'), manually set offset, limit and such but still no success.

Answer (score 1):

Though I have never had this requirement but your question look interesting & I did some googling.

I found two related modules. I think you should try them & see what they offer.

- [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc)
- [Views Aggregator Plus](https://drupal.org/project/views_aggregator)

*Note :- This is not an exact answer but helpful for these kind of situations :)*

Comment: Thanks. I've tried both but without success.